# Date to string Number format exception

Tags: java, type-conversion, numberformatexception

I'm trying the following code for date conversion into string, then to integer then some processing on the int and finally back to string, but I'm getting a `NumberFormatException`.

```
Date dNow2 = new Date( );
        SimpleDateFormat ft2 = 
        new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyyMM");
        String cnvrt=ft.format(dNow).toString();
        int cnvrtq=Integer.parseInt(cnvrt);
        int []cnvrtq2=new int[13];
        cnvrtq2[0]=cnvrtq-1;
        int l=0;

    for(int w=cnvrtq2[0];w>(cnvrtq2[0]-14);w--)
    {

        int y=w;
        y=y%100000;
        y=y%1000;
        y=y%100;

        if(y==0)
        {
            w=w-88;         
        }
        cnvrtq2[l]=w;
        l++;
    }

    String []cnvrtqw2=new String[13];

    for(int e=0;e<14;e++)
    {
        cnvrtqw2[e]=Integer.toString(cnvrtq2[e]);
        cnvrtqw2[e]=cnvrtqw2[e].substring(0,4)+"-"+cnvrtqw2[e].substring(5,6)+"-01      00:00:00.000";
    }

    for(int e=0;e<14;e++)
    {
        System.out.println(cnvrtqw2[e]);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you try to do? Sounds like you try to do something manually when you have enough Date APIs

Comment: please isolate the problem, format your code, and provide the exception

Comment: mistsake is on line int cnvrtq=Integer.parseInt(cnvrt); as i isolated code

Comment: solved guys the error was due to string was holding "-" characters which were not getting converted to integer

Answer (score 1):

`NumberFormatException` invoke when you are trying to convert invalid integer `string` to `int`

```
int a=Integer.parseInt("a");//here you will get NumberFormatException
```

it should be

```
int a=Integer.parseInt("5");//it works fine
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Date dNow2 = new Date( );
        SimpleDateFormat ft2 = 
        new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyyMM");
        String cnvrt=ft2.format(dNow).toString();
        int cnvrtq=Integer.parseInt(cnvrt);
        int []cnvrtq2=new int[13];
        cnvrtq2[0]=cnvrtq-1;
        int l=0;

    for(int w=cnvrtq2[0];w>(cnvrtq2[0]-14);w--)
    {

        int y=w;
        y=y%100000;
        y=y%1000;
        y=y%100;

        if(y==0)
        {
            w=w-88;
            //System.out.println("hellllllllllllllllllllllll");

        }
        //System.out.println(w);
        cnvrtq2[l]=w;
        l++;
    }
   // try
   // {
    String []cnvrtqw2=new String[13];
    for(int e=0;e<14;e++)
    {
        cnvrtqw2[e]=Integer.toString(cnvrtq2[e]);
    cnvrtqw2[e]=cnvrtqw2[e].substring(0,4)+"-"+cnvrtqw2[e].substring(5,6)+"-01      00:00:00.000";
    }

    for(int e=0;e<14;e++)
    {
        System.out.println(cnvrtqw2[e]);
    }
```

Try this. I think your mistake in `String cnvrt=ft2.format(dNow).toString();` as you write there `String cnvrt=ft.format(dNow).toString();`

Comment: int cnvrtq=Integer.parseInt(cnvrt);

Comment: You are creating object ft2. but in next line you write there ft.format(dNow).toString(); instead of ft2.format(dNow).toString();

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you tell which line it is that throws the exception. I suspect it is this one:

```
 int cnvrtq = Integer.parseInt(cnvrt);
```

What does `cnvrt` hold?

Comment: cnvrt shud hole the current date in string format as per the code

Comment: solved guys the error was due to string was holding "-" characters which were not getting converted to integer

Answer (score 0):

```
Store into cnvrtqw2[e] : 201306 2
Store into cnvrtqw2[e] : 201305 3
Store into cnvrtqw2[e] : 201304 4
Store into cnvrtqw2[e] : 201303 5
Store into cnvrtqw2[e] : 201302 6
Store into cnvrtqw2[e] : 201301 7
Store into cnvrtqw2[e] : 201212 8
Store into cnvrtqw2[e] : 0 9
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1946)
    at Test.main(Test.java:74)
Java Result: 1
```

in this Line

```
cnvrtqw2[e] = Integer.toString(cnvrtq2[e]);
            cnvrtqw2[e] = cnvrtqw2[e].substring(0, 4) + "-" + cnvrtqw2[e].substring(5, 6) + "-01      00:00:00.000";
```

In that place you are getting the value 0. But you are trying to get the subString Value. So only you got the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
`can you try it once...

 String dob="your date String";
 String dobis=null;
 final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
 final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 try {
  if(dob!=null && !dob.isEmpty() && dob != "")
  {
  c.setTime(df.parse(dob));
  int month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
  month=month+1;
  dobis=c.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-"+month+"-"+c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
  }

  } `
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
String date="20140809";
int numberDate=Integer.parseInt(date);
/* Whatever processing */
String date2=new Integer(numberDate).toString();
```